# Best technique to search for matching substrings with Linq & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, full-text-search, substring

I have a requirement to find rows in a table containing 200,000 entries. Some may not consider this 'large', but it is large enough to warrant performance considerations.

The table contains strings consisting of digits only. For instance, the user can enter something like '12340-0560-78', or portions of this, e.g. '0560', and I need to match values

12345678 and
123405678 and
0123456780 etc

These are NDCs, national drug codes, and in spite of the standard, manufacturers format them in a variety of ways by adding or omitting zeros in various positions in their barcodes.

I started out with letting Linq do the work, by removing zeros and non-numeric characters from the search string and using Contains() on the column after removing all zeros from it. This is too slow.

So I added a computed column to the table, containing the search column minus all zeros. This is better, but I am still doing a table scan due to the Contains().

I then created a full text index, but realized that with a full text index I cannot search for substrings, only for words, phrases, and prefixes. Strange, but it does not solve this problem.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just creating a simple clustered index on the computed column. Is the performance ok then?

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[foo](
    [code] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ccol]  AS (replace(replace([code],'-',''),' ','')
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_foo] ON [dbo].[foo] 
(
    [ccol] ASC
)
...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention - I did create an index on the computed column, otherwise it would not really provide any advantage. It works ok for now, and unless a better answer comes along, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would still give full-text index a try, but you have to prepare text for indexing in a certain way.

The idea is to create a separate `ndc_suffixes` column and populate it with all the suffixes of `ndc`. That is, for `ndc` = `'1234567890'` the `ndc_suffixes` will be `'1234567890 234567890 34567890 ... 890 90 0'`. This can be a [computed persisted column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx). Since NDCs are about 10 digits long, `ndc_suffixes` will take reasonable amount of storage (and it can be moved off to a separate table anyway).

Then a [full-text prefix search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) over `ndc_suffixes` could be used to get substring matches. Also an additional check `ndc like '%560%'` would likely be necessary to filter out bogus matches, but this one would be run over a significantly reduced set of rows.